# How to create an embed FROM your website?

Tags: html

It seems impossible to search this, so I'm asking this here. I'm currently making a web application, and I want to be able to let users embed from my website. How would I do this? Whenever I try to search for resources regarding this, results tend to speak about embedding from OTHER websites, when I'm trying to find a tutorial where users can embed from MY website. I'm trying to create a pomodoro timer that people can embed in their own websites, much like you can embed a YouTube video into your own HTML page. However, I have not been able to find resources regarding this.

Edit: Question was a little too broad, appreciate the input from everyone else on how to specify it. I wrote the question a little out of frustration, my bad.

Comment: Please attach an image of a prototype so we can see what you mean.

Comment: What do you mean by "embed"? Are you trying to include images/video/other pages? Are you trying to use iframes, or actually just let the user customise their version of the page? This question needs a bit more detail before it's answerable.

Comment: Are you trying to create an embed for other websites? For example, your embed is something I can put on my website, but it's an embed into yours?

Comment: It would be helpful to see an explanation of what the specific scenario you're trying to account for is. There are a lot of ways to embed content from your site onto another site. And there are a lot of things to consider like authentication and security depending on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to accomplish this. One way is to use IFRAME (youtube allows this for example) or you create a javascript snippet, that will make calls against your webserver or the API and render the data. You could event "inject" a new tag (Webcomponent-Style).

The best answer would be to take a look how others (Twitter, Youtube, Reddit) let you embed their stuff and from there on to choose what your fitting solution would be.

Your question is a bit broad and in any way specific. Please feel open to have a look at the [StackOverflow Guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: If you know the question is too broad/vague, generally you shouldn't answer it until it's clarified.

Comment: Already Flagged it. As you can see my answer is very broad, and due to the fact, that the person asking seems to ask his/her questions more specific, I just tried to help and hope that she/he clarifies his question... in dubio pro reo ^^